# Why do we first need the cd command when opening the .py file in the terminal by python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal

Why can't we open the .py file with its path by python?

noob asking. Apologies if I am stupid.

Comment: Please edit your question with your OS and the command you're running including the path (minus any sensitive information you don't wish to include)

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

If you have the file `/home/user/scripts/tests/main.py`, with the following content:

```py
print("Hello World")
```

Running `python3 /home/user/scripts/tests/main.py` will run the python script as expected.

There may be an issue with your `PATH` or with how you're entering the path to the file

Answer (score 0):

You probably use similar construction:

```sh
myscript.py
```

It means, that terminal consider your input as a command, and tries to find in in `$PATH`.

Firstly you need to use absolute or relative addressation:

```sh
./myscript.py
# or
/path/to/file/myscript.py
```

Secondly, you need to make sure, your script has an executable bit:

```sh
chmod +x myscript.py
```

Thirdly, make sure you use shebang in the first line of your scriptb:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
```

Shebang explains to your shell, which app should process the file.
Otherwise you'll need to run it via python directly:

```sh
python myscript.py
```